# Construct a transformation matrix from plane parameters

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, geometry, linear-transformations

I have a plane in 3D defined by a point and a normal, and an additional binormal vector (note the plane does not necessarily pass through the origin).

I need to find a transformation matrix $T$ such that if I take a point $p$ in the $xy$ plane I get a point $x,y,z$ in the aforementioned plane.

i.e. I am looking for the transformation matrix that takes the xy plane and turns it into this new plane.

A way to do it without matrices is, if $p$ is the point in the plane and $N, B$ are the normal and the binormal we can do:

$p + B\cdot V_x + (N \times B) \cdot V_y$

Where $V$ is a point in the xy plane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Please note that I try to keep this as simple as possible so that others, new members like myself, can understand this too.)

If we use $\vec{d}$ for 3D direction vectors and $\overline{p}$ for 3D position vectors, a 3D transformation matrix $\mathbf{M}$ is
$$\vec{d} = \left[ \begin{aligned} d_x \\ d_y \\ d_z \\ 0 \end{aligned} \right], \quad \overline{p} = \left[ \begin{aligned} p_x \\ p_y \\ p_z \\ 1 \end{aligned} \right], \quad \mathbf{M} = \left[ \begin{matrix}
X_x & Y_x & Z_x & T_x \\
X_y & Y_y & Z_y & T_y \\
X_z & Y_z & Z_z & T_z \\
  0 &   0 &   0 &   1 \\
\end{matrix} \right] \tag{1}\label{BtV1}$$
with the transformed vectors being $\mathbf{M}\vec{d}$ and $\mathbf{M}\overline{p}$ (i.e. we multiply vectors on the right of the matrix).

Vector $\overline{T}$ describes the overall translation (i.e., where origin is in the original coordinates after the transformation is applied), vector $\vec{X}$ describes the direction of the $x$ axis in the original coordinates after the transformation, and similarly $\vec{Y}$ for $y$ axis, and $\vec{Z}$ for $z$ axis:
$$\overline{T} = \left[ \begin{matrix} T_x \\ T_y \\ T_z \\ 1 \end{matrix} \right], \quad \vec{X} = \left[ \begin{matrix} X_x \\ X_y \\ X_z \\ 0 \end{matrix} \right], \quad \vec{Y} = \left[ \begin{matrix} Y_x \\ Y_y \\ Y_z \\ 0 \end{matrix} \right], \quad \vec{Z} = \left[ \begin{matrix} Z_x \\ Z_y \\ Z_z \\ 0 \end{matrix} \right] \tag{2}\label{BtV2}$$
As usual, transformation matrices can be multiplied, earliest right, latest left, to get the combined transformation:
$$\mathbf{M} = \mathbf{M}_{N} \mathbf{M}_{N-1} \dots \mathbf{M}_1 \mathbf{M}_0$$
and inverting the matrix yields the inverse transformation:
$$\overline{a} = \mathbf{M} \overline{b} \quad \iff \quad \overline{b} = \mathbf{M}^{-1} \overline{a}$$
and a simple algebraic formula exists for the inverse $\mathbf{M}^{-1}$, if and only if $\vec{X}\cdot(\vec{Y}\times\vec{Z}) \ne 0$.

(Programmers might be happy to know that the above scheme is used widely in 3D graphics, such as OpenGL and DirectX and others.)

$\eqref{BtV1}$ and $\eqref{BtV2}$ are really all we need to know, to construct the kind of transformations OP needs.

Essentially, $\overline{T}$ is the origin of the target plane; and $\vec{Z}$ is the normal of the target plane, $\vec{X}$ is the tangent vector to the plane, and $\vec{Y}$ is the binormal vector to the plane, using Frenet–Serret terms (*tangent*, *binormal*, and *normal*, for the three basis vectors in 3D, corresponding to the $x$, $y$ and $z$ axes in the transformed coordinate system).

As another example, let's say $\overline{c}$ is the origin of the target coordinate system (point where $(0,0,0)$ maps to), $\vec{n}$ is the plane normal but of unspecified positive length, and $\vec{u}$ is the plane tangent but also of unspecified positive length; and we want a scaling factor of $\lambda$ from the 2D to the 3D coordinate system, then
$$\begin{aligned}
\hat{n} &= \frac{\vec{n}}{\left\lVert\vec{n}\right\rVert} \\
\hat{u} &= \frac{\vec{u}}{\left\lVert\vec{u}\right\rVert} \\
\hat{v} &= \hat{n} \times \hat{u} \\
\end{aligned}, \quad \quad \begin{aligned}
\overline{T} &= \overline{c} \\
\vec{X} &= \lambda \hat{u} \\
\vec{Y} &= \lambda \hat{v} \\
\vec{Z} &= \lambda \hat{n} \\
\end{aligned}$$
This is particularly useful if you work with Frenet–Serret apparatus and want to derive the transformation at any point along the 3D curve as a single 4×4 transformation matrix.

Comment: Are you 100% sure the inside 3x3 matrix should not be transposed?

in this case the first row of the resulting vector would be $[X_x, X_y, X_z, T_x] \cdot V$, I think we want $$[X_x, Y_x, Z_x, T_x] \cdot V$$

Comment: @Makogan: Well spotted, indeed the $x$ component of $\mathbf{M}\overline{V}$ should be $X_x V_x + Y_x V_y + Z_x V_z + T_x$ (and not $X_x V_x + X_y V_y + X_z V_z + T_x$).  Fixed now, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For this, you will need to consider the projection matrix onto your 3D plane. This can be found by finding a matrix for which a vector is in the kernel if and only if it is a scalar multiple of the plane's normal vector.

Note: this will only work if your plane passes through the origin. Otherwise, you will need to add some constant after the transformation (matrices deal with vectors, not points).

So think of how you can construct a matrix whose kernel is only the span of the normal vector.

Comment: You should be able to add translation by going into higher dimensions, I don;t need the matrix to be 3x3, just to be able to express it as a matrix.